# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: vb.net, webclient

Olá,

Estou tentando logar no site e recebo a mensagem de erro:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

```
    Dim url As String = "https://www.academia.edu/login"
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Dim method As String = "POST"
    Dim parameters As New NameValueCollection()
    parameters.Add("login", "mylogin")
    parameters.Add("password", "mypass")
    Dim response_data As Byte() = client.UploadValues(url, method, parameters)
    Dim responseString As String = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(response_data)
```

Error:  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: a mensagem é clara, significa que o serviço que chamou disparou um erro. Precisa colocar isso num bloco de try catch para pegar a descrição do erro, mas pode começar analisando se a chamada está ok. É um POST mesmo? Os nomes dos parâmetros estão corretos?

Comment: Olá Ricardo, Tudo bem?  O que estou tentando é logar no site. Talvez o script não esteja correto . Se puder ajudar agradeço.